# Average of TextBoxes that are not blank

Tags: vba, excel

I need the average of five TextBoxes but there is a chance that some of them may be empty. If so, it should only consider the filled TextBoxes. I have some code to find the sum of those but couldn't succeed in finding the average:

```
 Tot = Tot + CDbl(TextBox117.Text)
 Tot = Tot + CDbl(TextBox118.Text)
 Tot = Tot + CDbl(TextBox119.Text)
 Tot = Tot + CDbl(TextBox120.Text)
 Tot = Tot + CDbl(TextBox121.Text)
 TextBox70.Text = Tot
```

I even tried counting the number of boxes but still couldn't get the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim arr, i As Long, n As Long, t As Double, v
arr = Array(TextBox117, TextBox118, TextBox119, TextBox120, TextBox121) 

n = 0
t = 0
For i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
    v = Trim(arr(i).Text)
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        t = t + CDbl(v)
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next i

TextBox70.Text = t
TextBox71.Text = t/n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim divNum As Integer
Dim Tot As Double
Dim numsAdd(4) As String
numsAdd(0) = TextBox1.Text
numsAdd(1) = TextBox2.Text
numsAdd(2) = TextBox3.Text
numsAdd(3) = TextBox4.Text
numsAdd(4) = TextBox5.Text

divNum = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(numsAdd)
    If numsAdd(i) <> "" Then
        Tot = Tot + CDbl(numsAdd(i))
        divNum = divNum + 1
    End If
Next i
 TextBox6.Text = Tot / divNum
```